# For some reason it does not perform the timer2_tick function

Tags: c#, timer

The program is supposed to call start timer1 when a button is clicked, timer1 is 17secs long. Then in timer1 it is supposed to start timer2, which is 8secs long. For some reason it does not perform the timer2_tick function.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] ProxList = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Prox.txt");

        string[] s = new string[4];            
        WinInetInterop.SetConnectionProxy(ProxList[p]);

        if (p > 3273)
            p = 0;

        s[0] = textBox1.Text;
        s[1] = textBox2.Text;
        s[2] = textBox3.Text;
        s[3] = textBox4.Text;

        try
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(s[txtBxNum]);

            timer2.Start();

            label1.Text = "Current Link: " + s[txtBxNum].ToString();
            label2.Text = "Current IP: " + ProxList[p].ToString();

            txtBxNum++;

            if (txtBxNum > 3)
                txtBxNum = 0;
        }
        catch { }

        p++;
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("skip_ad_button").InvokeMember("click");
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should remove those `catch { }`-Blocks and see if your code actually works.

Comment: Your document is probably loaded before you attach your event handler.

Comment: I put an exception in the catch block and i get an error on this line `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("skip_ad_button").InvokeMember("click");` saying System.NullReferenceException: Object not set to an instance of a object.

Comment: I have one question, when the timer2_tick is called does it perform this `webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;` once or until the timer finishes?

Comment: FJam: that line of code will be executed every time that `timer2_Tick` is executed. If you only want it to be executed once, then call `timer2.Stop` the first time that `timer2_Tick` is executed. That will prevent the timer from ticking multiple times.

Comment: Are you sure your `timer2_Tick` method does what you intended? (wiring up an event handler as opposed to calling it). If the document completed before this timer hits then this does nothing.